# Remove last comma in for loop using array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I'm stuck. I'm trying to remove the last comma at the back of the output but I just don't know how.

```
123, 97, 88, 99, 200, 50,
```

This is my code below, while checking for highest number in array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {4, 97, 123, 49, 88, 200, 50, 13, 26, 99};

    for (int i : array) {
        if (i >= 50) {
            System.out.print(i + ", ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: after the loop, just do a substring

Comment: Let me just share my previous answer regarding [StringJoiner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72236160/3393379)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix your code, I add a flag that indicates the first array element printed. For all subsequent array elements printed, I prepend the delimiter.

```
    int[] array = {4, 97, 123, 49, 88, 200, 50, 13, 26, 99};
    boolean first = true;
    for (int i : array) {
        if (i >= 50) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Running the above code prints the following:

```
97, 123, 88, 200, 50, 99
```

Alternatively, you can use [streams](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {4, 97, 123, 49, 88, 200, 50, 13, 26, 99};
    String result = Arrays.stream(array)
                          .filter(i -> i >= 50)
                          .boxed()
                          .map(i -> i.toString())
                          .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    System.out.println(result);
```

- `Arrays.stream` returns a stream of `int`
- `filter` keeps only those elements in the array that are >= 50
- `boxed` converts `int` (primitive) to `Integer` (object)
- `map` converts `Integer` to `String`
- `Collectors.joining` concatenates all elements in stream and separates each element with a comma followed by a space, i.e. `,`

Running the above code prints the following:

```
97, 123, 88, 200, 50, 99
```

Comment: Thanks! this also gave me new insights and mechanics to the solution of the problem.

Comment: Right my bad, the output was the same and the solution did just that. Thanks mate!

Comment: Haha, I'm still a bit incompetent at the moment since I'm still learning Java after a few weeks. However, I'll take my time to process and note all this methods.

Comment: @JohnNg I recommend Oracle's Java [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244976/discussion-between-john-ng-and-abra).

Answer (score 8):

One workaround here would be to *prepend* a comma to all but the first element in the array.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {4, 97, 123, 49, 88, 200, 50, 13, 26, 99};

    for (int i=0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        if (i > 0 && array[i] >= 50) {
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
        if (array[i] >= 50) {
            System.out.print(array[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This prints:

```
97, 123, 88, 200, 50, 99
```

**Edit:**

For brevity, and for the sake of using Java's internal APIs which already handle your requirement, we could just use `Arrays.toString` directly:

```java
int[] array = {4, 97, 123, 49, 88, 200, 50, 13, 26, 99};
String output = Arrays.toString(array).replaceAll("^\\[|\\]$", "");
System.out.println(output);
// 4, 97, 123, 49, 88, 200, 50, 13, 26, 99
```

Comment: I unroll your loop and understand your method but what if I also want to select only certain index more than or less than a value. E.g. for index more than 100, it will print only  `123, 200`.

Comment: @JohnNg That's not the question you asked, but in any case, my general answer should work with arrays of any size.  So if you feed in the array you want to view, it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, and to keep for-each statement:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {4, 97, 123, 49, 88, 200, 50, 13, 26, 99};

    boolean found = false;
    for (int i : array) {
        if (found) {
            System.out.print(", ");
        } else {
            found = true;
        }
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way you can do this. It makes use of the **StringBuilder** class:

```
int[] array = {4, 97, 123, 49, 88, 200, 50, 13, 26, 99};

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
for (int i : array) {
    if (i >= 50) {
        if (!sb.toString().isEmpty()) {
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        sb.append(i);
    }
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Output to console window will be:

```
97, 123, 88, 200, 50, 99
```